# For a stay exceeding 30 days does a US citizen require a visa in advance of arriving at the Philippines?

Tags: us-citizens, tourist-visas, visas-on-arrival, philippines

I am going to the Philippines to meet someone and because of the limited interval between receiving the money to buy the ticket and trying to arrive at least a few days before Valentine's Day, I am not going to have enough time to obtain a tourist visa beforehand. I want to be in the Philippines for 2 - 3 months.

Can I just purchase my ticket for a trip of more than 30 days, then get my tourist visa when I arrive in the Philippines?

Edit: I am a native born USA citizen leaving Florida. The time I will be receiving the money is between February 2nd and 8th. I have never traveled and don't have any visa.

Comment: As with all visa questions, we need your nationality. And if you have other visa or permanent residency in other countries that might be of influence you should add that as well.

Comment: Your nationality, current resident status, departure point is critical to get answers.

Comment: I do apologize for that, it was late and forgot that more than just people from US travel to Philippines too.

Comment: Just wondering--you're planning to use your tax refund money?

Comment: Lol, I am going to meet someone and start a new life, I know even if I don't meet this person, I will be able to meet plenty of other people in the Philippines and I personally feel to get adjusted to so much and enjoy every bit of the Philippines' life and culture.

Comment: I apologize, I pressed enter and thought it would create a new line. But to clarify, I am use tax refund money and student loan refund money to become an expat, to further my income, I am going to use much of that money into trading penny stocks, creating blogs, a Youtube channel, create games and apps.

However, either way, when I want to stay 30 or more days, I will need a VISA, I am simply seeking an answer to see if I could save money by not having to buy an extra plane ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I just purchase my ticket for more than 30 days then get my
>   tourist visa when I arrive in the Philippines?

I assume you know that you cannot "get a tourist visa" for Philippines when you are IN Philippines already; you can only extend your current stay. So I assume you are in essence asking "can I arrive to Philippines with a return ticket 2-3 months ahead, and manage to spend those 2-3 months in Philippines without leaving the country".

The answer is yes. The way it works is the following:

- You arrive to Philippines, and get a 30 day permitted stay at the immigration. Traveling on US passport I have never been asked for a return ticket ever in Philippines, or anything else.
- During those 30 days you apply for an [extension of stay for 29 more days](http://www.immigration.gov.ph/faqs/extensionofstay). I've done that, a simple and straightforward process (fill up a form, pay money, show up or send someone there with your passport, and get an extension). This gives you up to 59 days.
- After that you apply for another extension using what seem to be  [the same process](http://www.immigration.gov.ph/visa-requirements/non-immigrant-visa/temporary-visitor-visa/extension-of-authorized-stay-beyond-59-days), and this way you can apply for extension up to 36 months in 1/2/6 month incrementals. I have NOT been through this process myself, and don't know if you can apply for a longer extension right away when your 30 day stay is expiring (7 days before), or you can apply for three months right away; you'd have to check with the Immigration, or maybe someone else could chip in.

When you go to immigration, wear long pants, not shorts.

Comment: Thanks so much for the informative reply and your assumption is correct.

I do apologize for the poor formatting of the questions, this is my first time flying and as mentioned in the comments, I am going to become an expat, have high hopes that I meet someone, enjoy the culture and live a new life.

Furthermore, I am going to play it safe and have the return ticket before arrival.

Again, thank you so much.